# How can we best judge who has the skills to be a moderator?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderators

Some recent events have raised the question as to who is best equipped to be a moderator. It has become clear to me that some hugely valuable contributions are being lost to the site over concerns about moderation. Moderators here are elected by the community. What we mainly see when we vote is the contribution made in various ways. But the skills of contribution which are most valued on the site are not necessarily the skills required by a moderator - who has to make fine judgments about the behaviour of others, work constructively with other moderators, and continue to command the respect of the community as a whole.

There are some tools - badges etc - which indicate potentially positive moderator behaviour. But are there other things which ought to be rewarded, and is there a way in which the "potential moderator behaviour" of those who put themselves forward for election could be highlighted (as opposed to the basic business of asking and answering questions)?

I guess this is potentially a request for a feature to be added (moderator skills, at least at election time), or for some consideration of whether new badges might be desirable.

Comment: Hm, your first paragraph reminds me of the Peter principle - one gets promoted for doing a job good until end up at a job one doesn't do good..

Comment: One difficulty is that even if a moderator candidate causes concern among a large number of people who have noticed past problematic behavior, they can still easily be elected if popular among a large number of other people.  (Voting has very minimal requirements of involvement, and no requirement of paying attention.)  We cannot vote against a candidate, and there is (or at least hasn't been here) a clear platform for weighing such concerns during the election process.  I think the "primary" stage might help if we had it here, but we haven't; a candidate could nominate themselves last second.

Comment: Are you asking before or after they are elected?

Comment: The electoral process here has a fundamental flaw; namely that the easily identifiable merits of a potential moderator are based on their subject-matter expertise which, as it turns out here, is largely unrelated to the skillset required by moderation. One could read comment history and post history, but that is unreasonably difficult. And finally, after election, a moderator is judged only on actions, not intentions. Perhaps a transparent moderator form that the community could read, but not participate in, would help partly clear up that latter issue.

Comment: @EdGorcenski, a significant part of mod actions is motivatwd by information that is not public, as the content of flags, IPs of users, voting patterns &c

Comment: Although I think that most of the elected moderators have done a very good job, the election procedure itself does not impress me.  For one thing it seems to be designed for a site with about an order of magnitude more participation.  On this site, the election of moderators is more a self-selection than anything else.  It's less than clear to me how to improve the process (and even less clear whether the SE administration has any interest in this).

Comment: What I wanted to raise was the possibility of getting the best possible information before an election so we have a well-informed electorate. Is there fine tuning which would help?

Comment: One thing that struck me in the last election: I was surprised that a user who had been suspended (twice) in the relatively recent past was allowed to run for moderator.  Thinking idealistically I can see a rationale for this, but in practice I think that electing such a moderator is asking for trouble.  I might suggest that a user who has been suspended in the last year (say) be prohibited from running.   However the weirdly private/public mix of current suspension practices could make this hard to enforce.

Comment: Mark, the issue is that there is a good chance that most users simply don't care *enough* about that information.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I think the problem was rather that this moderator didn't disclose his suspension on the election question thread where all candidates where actually asked this question. I think a history of being suspended for spiteful downvoting doesn't look good to even the most superficial voter.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - that is the problem of democracy the world over. Is it worth trying to improve the process?

Comment: @Mark: I agree with both Pete and Michael's comment above. Disclosing suspensions (not necessarily with a reason, but at least disclosing that you *were* suspended twice, for example) would be a relevant details that may be helpful to incite a second thought in the casual voter. I have my doubts, though...

Comment: @Martin Sleziak :thanks for adding the tag I should have added - such attention deserves its proper reward.

Comment: @Michael: True, but I find myself more inclined to blame the process than the candidate for not disclosing information that would have hurt him in the election.  The current primary phase allows someone to sign up at the very end and skip directly to the voting: doesn't that defeat the point of having a primary?  Also, there is clearly some sentiment from the administration that one should not talk about suspensions (which I think is weird, given that you can immediately see when someone is suspended) which seems to provide some defense to the practice of nondisclosure of suspensions.

Comment: @Pete: I largely agree, but one technicality (if I have this right) is that while on larger SE sites there is a primary stage, the main purpose of the primary stage is (or was last I checked) to weed the candidate list down to 10.  Since our elections never had enough candidates, the primary stage was *skipped*, and we went straight from nominations to election. As you point out, another benefit of always having the primary stage would be the more adequate time to weigh the options.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark A suspension is not meant to be a permanent black mark on the user, if the user corrects his behaviour it is intentional that the suspension is pretty much forgotten in public. But I agree that previous suspensions should be made public in elections. This has happened in elections on other sites by regular users that remembered the suspension, but a more formal process would be useful.

Comment: @Pete: I fully agree. Under a different timing, the information would have probably been brought up by someone in the know.

Comment: @Mad Scientist: There are already some ways in which a suspension is a "permanent black mark" on the user: there is a very severe escalation in the duration of successive suspensions.  To the best of my knowledge, this is not time dependent.  In my opinion, this current practice is significantly more severe than the proposed practice of preventing a recently (by some definition) suspended user from becoming a moderator.  It doesn't make much sense to be "on probation" and at the same time be endowed with special status and responsibility.

Comment: @Pete L. Clark: In many countries, it is quite possible to previously be convicted of a crime (or even several crimes) and still be a candidate.  In some cases, one can even be in prison serving out a sentence.

Comment: @Henry B.: The former head of SE.com, Jeff Atwood, drove me nuts some years back by insisting on reasoning by analogy and metaphor. ("I'm a policeman...Like a university president, I....") One inevitably ends up arguing about various aspects of the analogy rather than what we want to be discussing.  I find it highly tedious.  If you have any remarks to make about this idea for a policy change on math.SE.com, I would be interested to hear them and might respond to them.  I am not interested in a lesson or debate on international penal codes and election laws.

Comment: @Jonas: Thanks, you're right.  I was confusing the "nomination" phase with the "primary" phase because on our site we never have ten candidates at a time and thus have no primary phase.  Again, this seems to be a sign that the election procedure was designed for a much larger group of participants than our site has.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I didn't mean to antagonize you. I hope it didn't come off that way.  I was thinking that invaluable experience about elections and voting exists in how current established voting systems work in the real world, and perhaps there was some insight to be have in the low bar for disqualification that many modern democracies seem to have.

Comment: Personally, I think that the election procedure is just fine as it is, and that, like any democracy, it relies on people _wanting_ to make an informed judgement and being prepared to invest time into that. This last assumption is almost always false, both on this site and elsewhere, but I am yet to see a democratic context where this problem has been solved. There was certainly no lack of available information about the candidates that were elected at the last election. The suspension history was well known and openly available on meta. So were other meta comments by the relevant people.

Comment: @Henry: Note that in a common democracy, even if the voter is trying hard it's hard not to have at least some media coverage. It would be impossible *not* to know that a candidate is a convicted man. On MSE the system requires digging through the meta to find such information.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I agree with you completely.  What could function as the equivalent of the media on MSE?

Comment: @Henry B.: No worries.  As I said, I got sensitized to this sort of thing by someone else.  I didn't mean to imply that one's general insights about punishment and elections were wholly irrelevant.  It's just that we are talking about a very specific group of people here who *do not* comprise a nation or anything like that.  We have our own policies and precedents and a very finite amount of leeway in changing things.  It really is its own thing.  Being suspended on math.se is really not like being in prison, and so forth.  Let's stay on topic.

Comment: @Henry, perhaps a rap sheet summarizing the number of votes; flags; edits; suspensions (just dates); and meta participation is to be shown by the user name before submitting the votes?

Comment: Also: suspension histories are in general *not* well known or openly available on meta.  In this case, one of a moderator candidate's suspensions was discussed on meta.  I'm not sure whether the other one was.  But as a general rule there is an "on the downlow" aspect to suspensions that I don't really understand.  For instance, on a thread describing recent events it is mentioned that there were *two* recent suspensions on this site.  Someone asked who else was suspended, and a moderator replied that that information is private...

Comment: ...Which I find strange given that a suspended user's webpage prominently displays that they are suspended and until what date.  In what sense then is being suspended a private matter?  If *present* suspensions are somehow private, are we sure it's kosher to bring up *past* suspensions during elections? (Perhaps one of the reasons it was *not* brought up explicitly last time is that those who knew about it wondered about the appropriateness of calling attention to it?)  Maybe it respects a user's privacy more to have them unable to run for moderator but not to tell anyone else about it?

Comment: It would be great to hear what worked and didn't work in the wider stack exchange network.  Although, I have seen some threads addressing the uniqueness of MSE in terms of moderation needs.

Comment: Are the current moderators well-enough trusted to propose a probationary period for new moderators?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Sounds not unreasonable, but likely to be controversial.

Comment: @Mark: On principle I don’t think that a probationary period with final judgement rendered by the longer-serving moderators is a good idea. While it would go some way towards ensuring that the moderators could work together, it would also run the risk of promoting a sort of inbreeding. I thought that it was a bit foolish to elect a firebrand with an agenda, but I’m not comfortable with a practice that could so easily tend to promote conformity.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - That's why the question of "well-enough trusted" approx $\equiv$ maturity of the site/community is relevant. Perhaps the answer is "not quite yet" and the current local difficulty is part of the process? But I think this is perhaps the right time for such a meta question to be asked - even if it is not quite yet time to give a definitive answer.

Comment: @Mark: I took ‘current moderators’ literally, to mean the ones that we have right now; did you mean ‘the sitting moderators, whoever they are at the time’?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - we live with what we have: I think you may have cross posted on my comments on maturity of the site, of which moderation is a significant part. We may still be exploring what good moderation is.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Though my opinions may not reflect what may actually be happening, but I think the problem with the electoral process is that on the campaign page a candidate's past history is not there for people to view, so e.g. people don't know if a particular candidate has had problems in the past. Also, I think that most people who vote have not been following events on meta and just vote for the person of highest rep.

Comment: There is a traditional test. Take the candidates to a stream to refresh themselves. Discard those who kneel and plunge their faces in the water to drink. Keep those who cup the water in their hands.

Comment: @Will: Or the variant, tie them to a chair and dunk them into the stream for ten minutes. Those who survive are clearly witches and therefore unfit to serve as moderators. Those who have drowned were clearly innocent people and should have been kept.

Comment: @Asaf: It's much easier to just see if they weigh the same as a duck.

Comment: @Arthur: That depends whether or not you want to reference Monty Python or The Simpsons. Either is fine... One can also go Futurama and shove a led pipe into the torso of the candidates, then see if it gets sawed off by itself and the body tissue quickly regenerate (although that could just be a case of worms).

Comment: @Asaf: Ofcourse it is: the whole business is a can of worms.

Comment: @BenjaLim One thing that is on the candidates page is his votes and for Bill, for example, you could see that he has a huge percentage of downvotes.  And, you can use a query on the data site to see he is one of the highest percentage downvoters there is.  And, that may not, by itself, tell you a whole lot.  But, it could be something to think about.

Comment: @Pete: I don't think the fact that an individual was suspended is _private_. I think the privacy only applied to _what led to the suspension_. To draw an extreme case, to fully disclose that an individual was suspended for using sockpuppets, we would have to show the evidence of IP address logs and access times and such, which would be against our privacy policy and potentially be illegal in various jurisdictions. Without the evidence it would just be my word against his word. Granted, it is a different issue with regards to rudeness or use of profanity on site, but when rule-making...

Comment: ...we must think at least a little bit about the edge cases.

Comment: @WillieWong I think one can separate the verdict and the process. If I would believe the mods are fabricating false evidence to kick of some user, I would start to run very fast. I think a more important issue is that we have lots of young people here and we do not want to ruin their future career by making it to easily accessible at a later stage what they did a long time ago and probably regret now. So some things can and should be more public than other things. When it comes to someone running for mod, a lot more should be public.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Just for clarification, by "verdict" do you mean not just that "so-and-so has been suspended X times, the first for Y days, the second for Z days..." but more along the lines of "so-and-so has been suspended X times, the first time for Y days _for Z reason_..." ? The former I don't think there's anything wrong with. The latter could be possible in principle, but we need to draw lines about what can be made public and what not, which would probably require a separate dedicated discussion.

Comment: @WillieWong I mean the latter. I guess we could have the discussion before the next election.

Comment: @Willie: Hi, I didn't see your reply until just now.  With regard to the issue of "privacy of suspension", I guess I am still a little unclear about the current policy.  As I said, a little while ago a moderator mentioned that a user other than Bill Dubuque had been suspended along with Bill, someone else asked who that was, and the moderator replied but declined to divulge that information.  Does that mean that the information is "private"?  Anyway, it seems that the policies regarding suspension are rather vague, even to the moderators: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1442.

Comment: @Pete: I think there are two types of privacy here. What I mentioned above are more about the [privacy policy](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) sense of the word, that there are certain information which are _not_ available to general users and only to moderators which we are bound by the moderator agreement not to divulge. Those are mandated for us to be in the most conservative sense compliant with known laws in various countries (in particular the EU, which is especially stringent about this).

Comment: @Pete: what you referred to, if I were to guess, is more the interpersonal sense of privacy. There are some of our dirty laundry which we would not like to see aired out all the time. As decent human beings we try not to bring that up in polite company when unnecessary. But since a "suspension" results in a publicly viewable message on said user's profile, the fact that a user has been suspended is by design something that is not protected under the privacy policy. (And indeed, certain bystanders during that event know well who the other party is.)

Comment: @Pete: by the way, in [my comment here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/how-can-we-best-judge-who-has-the-skills-to-be-a-moderator#comment25168_6835), when I say a line needs to be drawn, it is probably more in the latter sense of the word. It is true that the _actual reason_ for the suspension is generally not publicly available. But said reason itself is usually insufficient as personally identifying information, so releasing that would not technically run contrary to the privacy policy. We will never go anywhere near the hard line already drawn up by the privacy policy.

Answer (score 31):

Not only does the community not have much basis to evaluate moderator candidates, but we then must elect them for life.

I think it would be helpful if moderators were initially elected to a probationary term of fairly short duration (say, 3 months).  At the end of this term, the community could evaluate their work (based on either detailed or aggregate data about what moderator actions they have taken, as well as comments from fellow moderators), and vote on whether to retain them.

Actually, I happen to think *all* moderators should run for re-election periodically; I dislike the current moderator-for-life system.  But at a minimum the community should get at least one chance to make a decision about a moderator based on his or her actual performance.

Comment: Oh, I see this was already proposed and discussed in comments.  Well, this way people can vote on it.

Comment: Yea, I read a bunch of comments (there are 50+ comments) and didn't see this so it's good it's an answer.  +1, most definitely should have a probationary period since we can't really judge them as moderators until they are moderators.

Comment: I agree in principle that it would be nice to somehow check up on people who may have sounded good in their nomination but didn't turn out to be good moderator material in practice, but the unfortunate side-effect of a probation period is that you'd see newly elected moderators being *very* conservative and hesitant during that probation period because they'd be motivated by getting "confirmed into the role" at the end of it. Moderators have to be able to take the sometime unpopular actions and "get X votes or you're out" systems hamstring that.

Comment: With all that said, we recently put up a [process for removing a moderator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157258/155160) that is largely driven by other moderators on the site (mostly since they're privy to all the information that goes into evaluating a moderator's actions), but could also be initiated by the site's users if there are enough issues to convince the other moderators that a moderator is not working out.

Comment: I didn't realize before that the election term was unlimited. I thought it was for one year.

Answer (score 28):

This is a poll.  Please vote this answer up if you think there should be a delay between the deadline for nominations and the beginning of voting.  This has been mentioned in several comments; I am posting it as an answer just so that it can be put to a vote.

Comment: Could you not make this into a new thread, with other ideas which have been put forward which we could vote on also?

Comment: I'm interested to know how such feature should be implemented...

Comment: @Asaf: several people have mentioned a "primary" feature built into the software already, although I don't understand it yet. Or we could just enforce it as a community by requiring candidates to pre-commit before the "official" deadline. But I wrote the question just about whether the delay is desirable, independent of how it would be implemented.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: See the end of [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6918/10513) of MadScientist.

Answer (score 23):

How about this as a feature request?

It is certainly fine that a person have privacy if suspended.  But, if they want to run for moderator, then they must surrender that privacy and it must be made known of their past suspensions, including some detail as to what happened and why they were suspended.  If they don't want people to know about their suspensions, then they can have the privacy by simply not running.  But, if you put your name in as a candidate, you are expressing that you are giving up your right to the privacy.  This is how it goes in real life when someone runs for an office.  We need to know if they did terrible or stupid things so we can make a decision.

And, there could be a time limit on this, perhaps it only is necessary for suspensions in the last year.  So, if a user can behave for over a year, then they can have the privacy and still run to be a moderator.

Comment: I also think the number of times their comments have been flagged as offensive needs to be disclosed.

Comment: @user10389: I think that is less informative because anyone can flag the comment; it isn't a deliberative process. But suspensions are not made lightly, and so knowing about them gives more information.

Comment: @CarlMummert In addition to disclosure of suspensions, comments that were removed by a moderator because they were abusive/offensive.

Answer (score 14):

On the election candidate page you can find the number of helpful flags the user have raised, and the number of meta posts. Those things indicate the level of involvement of the user in the moderation of the site, to some extent at least.

I think that in the next election reviews statistics may be applicable as well, although I'm not 100% positive how that would be relevant. It would show, though, that the user is interested in improved the site and is willing to invest in it.

Unfortunately this is quite moot. The voting itself has always ended up to those with most reputation, as if people correlate between the ability to write good/popular answers to the ability to make managerial decisions.

In recent elections one of the elected candidates refused to answer my questions to the candidates on grounds that they are too busy improving the site, and answering a petty question like mine is a waste of time. They will answer it, later -- when time permits. In fact I don't recall that particular moderator answering many questions anyway.

Needless to say, that candidate was elected, and then we had that mini-fiasco with flagging which proved that new moderators which are unexperienced in actual moderation on this site -- make bad moderators (at first, anyway).

---

The problem is to get voters involved in the meta site; even just reading is a start. I am more than certain that if everyone who voted were regular meta visitors the results would have been different.

So the feature request, while noble, should be different. It should force the candidates to be active on meta, and it should semi-force the voters to follow that.

If anything, then my idea (which is definitely not a good one, but may be a start for some other idea) would be to extend the time between the primaries and the elections to two weeks (or a month) and force the candidates to be active on the meta. There is a lot to show in two weeks, and later it is easier to call someone on a broken promise; or to point out discrepancies between what the candidates say before the elections and what they did before it.

Comment: I think the "active on meta" idea could have some traction. An informed electorate is a prerequisite of true democracy.

Comment: I don't think we should try to force most people to be active on meta. I look at meta from time to time and there is rarely anything for me to comment on. I could *force* myself to comment, but that seems like a waste of time when I could use my limited time on the site to answer questions. I do think that having a reasonable period of time (say 1 week) between nominations and voting would give the average user a *reason* to use meta during that time, and it would also give voters a written record they can look at before voting.

Comment: @Carl: I agree with what you said.