# How to ensure candidates pre-commit for next election

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, moderators, election

This is a follow up to [How can we best judge who has the skills to be a moderator?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6835/630) . Two moderators have recently resigned, and they say there will be another election soon. Some recent elections had problems that candidates "self-nominated" extremely close to the deadline, with one particular example which led to the thread linked above.  The community needs to find a way to weigh concerns with candidates before the election process.

Is there an technical means to require candidates to self-nominate earlier, or to put a pause between the nomination phase and the voting phase?  I have heard rumors of a "primary" system in the SE software, but I am not sure how to make it happen.

Answers from SE developers about exactly what influence the community has on the election process, and about the "primary" option, would be particularly welcome.

Edit: at the request of Shog9, I have also tagged this as feature-request.

Comment: I believe that there is a reasonable chance that we will have more than the minimal ten, but perhaps we can arrange 10 users who will be willing to "buff up the numbers".

Comment: I do think that getting 10 should be possible. The deeper question is how to organize a discussion of the candidates, particularly because the primary is done with a system like a regular question - but with comments disabled. Therefore a separate system would be needed to allow for comments to be posted.

Comment: Carl, I am certain that 10 people won't be needed. The last election we had exactly 10 people on the first candidacy, and I doubt we will end up with less than eight. This means that you really just need two people. Unless you are planning to run yourself for moderator, me and you make two people and I am sure we can find a third. Besides I always wanted to try to some real life aspects of forcing, for example forcing primaries! :-)

Comment: @CarlMummert SE organizes a town hall chat with the candidates where the community can ask all the candidates. The results are collected and posted in a meta question.

Comment: @MadScientist, but this is not enough... as the last elections show. Many people felt that if there was a forced primaries then the extra week would have given the voters so more time to roam around the meta and whatnot.

Comment: @Mad Scientist: the concern is more with candidates who don't answer questions; the delay of the primary gives others adequate time to make statements, politick, etc.

Comment: @AsafKaragila A site of this size should have enough candidates for a primary, I expect this election to have one. And while I think the timing between town hall chats and the end of the election could be better (but very hard to do because scheduling is always difficult), I'm not sure how many users actually research the candidates and look beyond the nomination page.

Comment: @MadScientist: After Bill was out of the moderator team and left the site more than one person said that they wished they had more time to know about the candidates, and that they would have considered not voting for Bill if they knew his history a little bit better. Indeed not everyone look past the nomination page, but the extra week *is something*. It can also force the candidates to answer more questions properly (again, see the way Bill responded to my questions "I don't have time to answer that right now" sort of comment), and that is a big deal.

Comment: Related: I suggest that the future candidates be required to address precisely the "homework/no effort/close" hot issue. What they think about it, and what they plan to do about it, if anything. I suspect most of them will, anyway.

Answer (score 7):

The primary phase will automatically happen if more than 10 users nominate themselves. Comments on nominations are not visible in the primary phase itself, so this does not really help all that much if a user intents to avoid them.

The best way to address concerns about some candidates is the election town hall chat (or the offline version that SE is testing, I don't know which one will be used here). There you can ask the candidates questions, though candidates might not attend it and might also avoid answering the questions later. But then the voters can draw their conclusions from the silence of the candidate.

Comment: Thanks. I found http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work/135361 which does say no comments are allowed on the primary phase voting page - so presumably we have to start another meta post for comments? If that page is accurate, candidates may withdraw as soon as the primary begins, which means that any 10 members can force a primary by self-nominating and then withdrawing.

Comment: We will be using the non-live version for testing here, so, it will be a Q&A that we collect questions for a few days and then a second thread will provide a questionnaire for candidates to answer. Let it be said that not only is the questionnaire optional, but **this should not stop the community from organizing their own community chat session for a Q&A with the candidates**.

Comment: @GraceNote How does the timing work with the new system? There is no need to find a time for all candidates to appear in chat anymore, and as it is asynchronous the questions could be collected pretty early. I always found it odd that the town hall happened while we were already voting (in the primary or the main election).

Comment: @MadScientist I start collecting Q&A at the end of the nomination phase, so that all candidates are already present. The question collection lasts for 2 days (we might cut it shorter, maybe, in testing, and I guess it's possible to start in advance of the end of the nomination phase), and then the questionnaire is posted for candidates to respond. It coincides with voting time mostly under the expectation that voters take advantage of having a whole week to vote, instead of just voting the moment the poll doors open.

Comment: @Grace Note: is there a link from the voting page to the meta thread which collects questions and answers from candidates? That would seem like a helpful way to encourage voters to investigate the candidates. The previous system led voters directly to the voting page, and I had the impression it did not encourage informed voting.

Comment: @Carl We can add a link to the elections page and have been doing so for the recent elections. Our current approach is to include it, alongside a few other links to statistics and the chatroom, just before the actual list of candidates. This is probably not the most ideal situation (and one consistent request I get is to link each individual's answers from their personal nomination), but at the moment we don't have anything more prominent setup.

Comment: That sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 7):

First off, let's have a bit of background:

- The total election will be 15 days long.
- The nomination phase will be 7 days long.
- The primary voting phase - if it happens - will be 4 days long.
- The final voting phase will be 4 days long *if there is a primary*, otherwise 8 days long.

We can and will remove any candidates who nominate "in bad faith" - effectively this means anyone whose nomination clearly indicates they've no desire to actually participate in moderating the site won't be allowed to run. So, **no gaming the system to force a primary voting phase.**

We'll also provide a dedicated chat room to discuss the candidates (linked to from the election page) as well as a thread here on Meta to pose questions to the candidates and another where they'll be expected to provide answers (we're transitioning to this system over the old chat-based "town hall" format for expediency and to improve visibility). Both of these will be available throughout the voting period, and should go a long way toward addressing concerns over the ability of voters to get their concerns about candidates addressed.

That said, if you *really, really want it*, we can force a primary phase - just bear in mind that in order for this to happen *someone* is going to be eliminated before the final election. There'll be four moderators elected this time around - if only 4 people make it into the final phase of the election (or 5 into the primary), we'll cancel the election (because at that point you could win just by running).

Please tag all meta discussions regarding changes to the election process with [election](/questions/tagged/election) + [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Comment: "We can and will remove any candidates who nominate "in bad faith" - effectively this means anyone whose nomination doesn't clearly reflect an honest desire to moderate the site won't be allowed to run."  Isn't it the job of the voters in an election to evaluate the sincerity of the candidates?  Does this avowed policy make anyone else uncomfortable, or is it just me?

Comment: @Pete: wasting voters' time with joke nominations doesn't exactly encourage voters to focus on the important task of examining the trackrecords of serious candidates.

Comment: We have never had a problem of too many nominees for an election nor, in my opinion, any obviously frivolous nominees.  So in response to an issue which is at best hypothetical, you have said that you "can and will" interfere in an election in the most severe way, namely by throwing out candidates using the criterion "doesn't clearly reflect an honest desire to moderate the site".  You do live in a democratic republic, right?  How would you feel if your state government assured you that it could and would dismiss candidates who did not evince "honest desire" to serve?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark In my observation SE has been very careful when using their ability to retract nominations, I've only seen it used for clear joke nominations. I understood it in this case that anyone stating "I'm nominating to force a primary, but don't vote for me as I don't really want to be a mod" will have their nomination removed. And the removal of nominations is something the community notices in my experience, and any abuse by SE would certainly generate a very public discussion.

Comment: @Mad Scientist: your comment sounds very reasonable.  I hope you can see though that this is not at all what "Shog9" said.  If "Sh0g9"'s position is not truly representative of the SE team, I would very much like to hear it.  To be more precise, eliminating any candidate who **says** that they are not interested in being a moderator is completely unobjectionable.  But Shog9's comment says that he *will* impose a much stronger standard than this, by throwing out candidates whose motivations are not clear *to him*.  That's a problem for me.

Comment: I think that there is significant support for a primary phase. What is really desired is a substantial delay between nominations and voting to allow for candidates to be vetted, but the primary seems to be the only way to do this at present. If there is a way to ensure a primary regardless of the number of nominees, or some other way to give us time to discuss the nominees, I would support it.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I've discussed this issue with Shog in the past (I'm a moderator on two other sites), and I think the way he has written the SE position here can easily be misread. His position is representative of SE, but the way you're reading this post is not his actual position. SE is not really evaluating the candidates "honest desire to moderate", but only removes the most blatant joke nominations.

Comment: @MadScientist: As I said, if what was written in this answer is not indicative of the actual SE position -- or, especially, if it is not indicative of the actual position of its author -- I very much hope it will be amended.  Until that happens, I have to respond to what was actually written and record that I find it problematic.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Don't forget that this answer was prompted by several suggestions in the comments on the question and Mad Scientist's answer that folks should put up fake nominations in this election just to beef up the numbers.

Comment: @Anna Lear: nobody suggested putting up "fake" nominations - rather they suggested putting up *actual* nominations for the purpose of ensuring a primary. I have been ignoring that part of Shog's statement, which I found to be at best tone deaf and out of agreement with the SE theory of moderator elections laid out at http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/ - "We gladly reciprocate by trusting you to lead and govern your own community." I would suggest to everyone that we should move past Shog's unfortunate phrasing and focus on more productive issues.

Comment: @Carl: sounds like you're assuming bad faith on our part. Yeah, we'll trust members of a site to self-govern, up until the point where an individual makes it obvious that's not his intention (and yes, folks actually do this). I've tweaked the wording there a bit.

Comment: @Shog9: the issue with your wording is that you assume that forcing a primary phase is "gaming the system"; if the consensus of the Math.SE community is that we want a primary, then it is not gaming the system to ensure that a primary happens, it is simply making the best of a system that we have to use. However, if it is already possible to ensure a primary *regardless of the number of nominations* (which is likely to be close to 10 anyway), and you could assure us that a primary will indeed happen "no matter what" then the entire issue can be behind us.

Comment: For reference, the issue of wanting a pause was discussed at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/6921/630

Comment: I am very glad to hear this. I also support a forced primary phase. If the previous election had ten folks running, I am certain there will be more this time, but even more certain that there won't be less. So if we weed out from 10 to 9 or 8, it's fine with me.

Comment: @CarlMummert As Shog mentioned in his post, a primary doesn't actually make the election any longer, it just splits the election phase into two parts. Forcing a primary won't help with the actual issue here, strong participation from the community in the Q&A for candidates will.

Comment: @Carl: if you want to force a primary, then suggest that (post a feature-request) - if folks support it, we can make it happen. That's the honest way to go about this. Nominations from folks who don't want to moderate but run anyway are misleading (or at best distracting) to voters who don't know the reasoning behind them - and frankly, I don't think y'all need to risk electing another moderator who doesn't want to moderate.

Comment: @Shog9: I did tag this thread as "support". If you have the means to force a primary to occur, please let us know if you will do so. Please do not imply that an action taken after significant open discussion on meta would be dishonest in some way.

Comment: @Mad Scientist: the point if the primary is mainly to delay voting - I suspect few revisit their votes after they are cast, and the system starts encouraging voting as soon as the election begins.

Comment: I appreciate the rewording of the answer, and I no longer object to it.

Comment: @CarlMummert The point of the primary isn't to delay voting. That's just a side-effect. The point is to narrow down the pool of candidates to the top X most viable through publicly visible voting. At least one person is eliminated, and this is done to make the final election phase easier and more meaningful.

Comment: @Anna Lear: indeed. If you read the question, however, the goal of the community is to delay the voting. The only reason to talk about a "primary" is that it seems to be the only method the SE software provides to achieve that goal. If there is some other method to achieve the goal, that would be great to hear.

Comment: @CarlMummert The thing we're trying to caution against here is forcing the primary to be this delay. It may be the closest and only option, but it is not designed to work the way you want it to. We have considered putting a delay between nominations and (any type of) voting, but ultimately decided not to do that because it would likely lead to loss of interest in the election. What happened on Math in the last election is highly atypical, and we'd rather not make changes to the whole system without carefully considering long-term implications.

Comment: @CarlMummert In the meantime, we put a process in place to allow communities and moderators to remove moderators who turn out to be poor fits for the job and/or the community. That should handle the vast majority of cases where someone gets elected when they should not have been. (Come to think of it, there *haven't* been any egregious cases like that anywhere yet. We're still waiting for our first case of a moderator getting deposed by his/her peers.)

Comment: @Anna Lear: It is up to the math.SE community to decide how we want to use the primary; remember that SE says "We don’t run Stack Overflow. You do. ... We gladly reciprocate by trusting you to lead and govern your own community." What happened in the last election did happen, and the community is looking for a way to avoid it recurring. The point of the question was to determine *how* to accomplish what the community wants to do.  If SE prefers to implement another way, to help us out, that would be wonderful. If a primary is the only way, it seems likely we'll have one.

Comment: @CarlMummert As Shog said, if you guys really want a primary, we can arrange that. Just be aware of its limitations and please don't try to work around the system with something like fake nominations designed to force said system to work another way.

Comment: @Anne, Shog, I have one point and one question about the election. First the question, how many of the votes in the previous election were not cast within the first three days? Second, the idea of a primary stage is important because it allows you to re-visit your decision. I'm not sure everyone who voted on the first day would revisit their decision, even if that's possible to do. But if you are *forced* to recast the votes you may choose differently.

Comment: Or you might not choose at all, @Asaf. There's always a trade-off in these things - and the hard truth is that many eligible voters already don't vote *once*. This is why I have to insist on a specific feature-request here so everyone who cares knows what's going on - while a forced primary *might* help, it's not free.

Comment: Shog9, I have no problem with a specific thread. But in order to decide for myself whether such thread is even worth opening, I am trying to gather some statistical data first.

Comment: @Shog9:  A substantial number of people at Math.SE would like a delay between the nomination phase and the voting phase, indicated by upvoting this question and at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/how-can-we-best-judge-who-has-the-skills-to-be-a-moderator/6921#6921 .  The point of the question is to figure out how to achieve the delay, and I am not sure how to be any more clear about the desired outcome. This site is self-governing - it is not the role of SE.com to debate the *desirability* of the delay. Please tell us whether there is a way besides a primary to achieve it.

Comment: @CarlMummert I'm not trying to create busywork here, but please open a *new* question that's going to serve as a feature request for the primary instead of just retagging this one. The discussion in this thread has gone in several directions and the votes on this question in no way reflect voting on the specific request to force a primary. Linking back to this question would likely help establish context, but a very specific (and new) request would better allow folks who might disagree to speak up. Thanks!

Comment: @Anna, Shog: What will happen if the elections are canceled? (If you prefer me to open a new thread, let me know.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila That is an excellent question. We currently don't have a firm plan for a cancelled election - it's never happened before. Most likely, we will process the resignations that are still pending and the remaining moderators will be overworked for a while as discussions on how to handle things proceed. Fingers crossed that things don't come to that.

Comment: @Anna: Thank you. Let us hope that it doesn't happen.